# Connecting Android mobile to Mail Exchange Server

Tags: email, exchange

I am currently pursuing a project, and need to connect my Android device to an Exchange mail server. I am having a problem connecting my Android mobile to a Windows server. Could any body please guide me through it? Do I need to connect it using EDGE, GPRS, or Wi-Fi?

Comment: In my case it works without any problem it, detailed descriptions of the problem may be helpful

Comment: I agree, we need a detailed description of what you're doing and what is resulting.  Your credentials, port settings, etc. are probably slightly off.

Comment: The version of Android will be key here, as there were a number of improvements to connecting to Exchange in Froyo.

Answer (score 3):

In order to connect your phone to an Exchange account follow these steps:

1. From the home screen hit the menu button and choose "Settings".
2. Choose "Accounts & sync".
3. Click the "Add account" button on the bottom.
4. Choose "Corporate".
5. Enter the full E-mail address and Password of the Exchange account you're trying to link, then click "Next".
6. This step may require you to contact your Exchange server administrator.  You will need to know the name of the domain on which the Exchange server resides, and then enter it in the first field before the "\".  Leave the Password field alone, and make sure that the Server field lists either the IP address of your Exchange server or the name (commonly something like "mail.mycompany.com").  Depending on how the Exchange server is set up you may need to check or uncheck the two boxes below the Server field, but usually the defaults work fine.  Then hit "Next".
7. Agree to the disclaimer (all it says is that the administrator of the Exchange server has the ability to wipe any Exchange-related information from your phone without your permission) and you should be all set!

If everything went according to plan you should start receiving E-mails right away in the E-mail app.

**Edit:** These steps should work for Android 2.2 and definitely work for 2.3.